# Plotly Choropleth showing no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to plot choropleth map using plotly but getting a blank output.I am not getting any map.here is my code-
input-

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
%matplotlib inline
data = dict(type = 'choropleth',
        locations = ['AZ','CA','NY'],
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        colorscale= 'Portland',
        text= ['text1','text2','text3'],
        z=[1.0,2.0,3.0],
        colorbar = {'title':'Colorbar Title'})
 layout = dict(geo = {'scope':'usa'})
 choromap = go.Figure(data=[data] , layout=layout)
 iplot(choromap )
```

output-
it is a blank screen. I am sharing my screenshot.What is the issue?
Thank you in advance

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14R6zfNxnefBoe3RFlFH2YunlTbrFzfRX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Just double click on the white space and you will get the desired output.
This worked for me.
Thanks